# Does P4V support dragging a text file into Visual Studio or other editors?

Tags: perforce

In p4Win, one could drag a text file from a pending changelist into a text editor, such as Visual Studio (almost anywhere in the window) and it would open up the file. Instead p4V pastes the path of the file, and there is not way to drag/drop/open the file as easily. Is this maybe configured somewhere in the settings?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to UAC on windows 10. Disabling UAC fixes the problem.